# Where does Android store SQLite's database version?

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I am unable to find where Android stores the database version within the SQLite database file. Where exactly is the database version stored?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You can read the version using `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getVersion()`.

Internally, this method executes the SQL statement "[`PRAGMA user_version`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_schema_version)". I got that from the [Android source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java#L861).

In the database file, the version is stored at byte offset 60 in the [database header](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#database_header) of the database file, in the field 'user cookie'.

Comment: that was useful, but my question is where does this version info get stored on the filesystem (or may be in database file)?

Comment: And to read and modify it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030779/change-sqlite-database-version-number

Comment: how is the database version persisted into the database file?

Comment: @xuehui see the answer: byte 60 in the database file.

Answer (score 11):

If someone is looking for the java code to read version from file:

```
private static int getDbVersionFromFile(File file) throws Exception
{
    RandomAccessFile fp = new RandomAccessFile(file,"r");
    fp.seek(60);
    byte[] buff = new byte[4];
    fp.read(buff, 0, 4);
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(buff).getInt();
}
```