# Change SQLite Database Version Number

Tags: android, sqlite, version

I have a database that I built in SQLite browser, and it works fine. I launched an app with a prebuilt database and now I want to add more tables and data to that database.

I can get the app to launch the `onUpgrade()` method of the `SQLiteOpenHelper`.  But the problem is, it's doing that EVERY time I use the helper.

I have it localized to, only on app launch, separating the upgrade command from the helper I used to retrieve data, but this is still a problem.

I have figured it out though, as I have been using the same database on my computer (the one that I'm editing) since version 1. So, whenever it writes the newer database onto the SD card it's showing version 1 even though I should be up to version 4 by now.

So, my question is, how can I manually edit the database version of the original database so that when it updates it isn't writing the old version number over the new one?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

To manually update the version to 4 you execute the following SQL statement:

```
PRAGMA user_version = 4
```

Answer (score 11):

Another way to change the version of your Sqlite Database. You can use DB Browser for SQLite:

1. Open the database file with "DB Browser for SQLite".
2. Change the "User Version" number to whatever number you want
3. Click the "Save" button
   [image: Sqlite Database Browser]

Answer (score 8):

You can also set it via the `setVersion` SqlLiteDatabase method.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setVersion(int)