# Can I determine the Android database version using SQLiteManager?

Tags: android, sqlite, version

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707797/where-does-android-store-sqlite-database-version), the Android database file contains the version number.  However I can't figure out how to find it using SQLiteManager for Firefox.

Is it possible to view the version using this tool?

Comment: execute `PRAGMA user_version;` in the same place you can execute other SQLite queries - that will show you the version set by `SQLiteOpenHelper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@zapl wrote:

> `execute PRAGMA user_version`; in the same place you can execute other
>   SQLite queries - that will show you the version set by
>   SQLiteOpenHelper