# Android check SQLite database version via shell?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707797/where-does-android-store-sqlite-database-version) is there a way to check the app's current database version via adb shell? Also how do I check the `user cookie` field mentioned in the question?

Comment: You could show the SQLite version by executing `SELECT sqlite_version();`, but this is not the version number you want; you want the database version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To show the database file's [user version number](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_schema_version) (which is the same as the user cookie), execute this SQL command:

```
PRAGMA user_version;
```

Answer (score 0):

To check the sqlite version through shell, follow below commands:

```
adb -s <deviceId> shell
sqlite3 /data/data/<your app's package name>
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb