# What is the full scope of the SQLite Database version number?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I've spent quite some time reading what I can find about the often confusing and often dreaded ***SQLite Databse Version Number***. I've found out that it is apparently stored in the Database header file 60bytes in as per:- [Where does Android store SQLite's database version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707797/where-does-android-store-sqlites-database-version)

I've gone to quite some lengths to get around it. Created classes (`DBDatabase`, `DBtable` and `DBColumn`) and quite a few methods that allow me to basically have an *awayfrom-the-database* schema.

One of the cumulative methods `actionDBAlterSQL` compares the SQLite schema via PRAGMA for all tables and columns and will then run generated `ALTER` statements to `ADD` any columns that have been added.

To invoke this I've added an `onExpand` method in the `DBHelper` and thus get around version control.

I'm still testing things, but it certainly works in principle. I've added and columns just by making a few changes in a single block of code specifically for the purpose of relatively easily managing the schema/design (and if things go that way other projects that I am involved with).

However, I can find very little about the actual scope of the Database Version number other than that an increase to the version results (when done correctly) **`onUpgrade`** being invoked.

My main interest revolves around  the question; Am I going to end up breaking anything by circumventing using the version number?

I'd also like to know if I'm missing out on any useful features; perhaps rollback to a previous version of the schema or even data (I've not seen anything related so I suspect that isn't the case).

Is it perhaps just a convenience, as such, and basically just a number that if increased allows **`onUpgrade`** to run? It's the suspicion that this is the case that diverted me along this path :).

Additionally the subject of how to successfully work with the version number appears to be quite a frequent question, as such perhaps any findings here could be of assistance to others.

Comment: I should say I've been to [SQLite Android Bindings](https://www.sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) numerous times. It doesn't appear to have any relevance (unless the links are really saying go and look at the source code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database version number is just a convenience, and basically just a number that if increased allows `onUpgrade` to run. (See the implementation of `getDatabaseLocked()` in the [SQLiteOpenHelper source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java).)

To get around the version number handling, just don't use the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class. (You can instead use `SQLiteDatabase` directly.)

Comment: So simple, yet so confusing considering that you so often see words that effectively say you must use the version to change the schema.